# Change Dovecot to allow IMAP folder names with '.' like "test.com"

Tags: server, mail, dovecot

I have problem in migrating email folders, because many use a '.' in the folder names.

I found out that the current dovecot default for the hierarchy separator in Ubuntu is '.'. That makes it a forbidden char in a folder name, as far as I understood. I would like to change to '/' as described in the commented out config section.

This is the output from dovecot -n on the test installation:

```
mail_location = maildir:~/Maildir
namespace inbox {
inbox = yes
location = 
 mailbox Drafts {
special_use = \Drafts
}
 mailbox Junk {
 special_use = \Junk
 }
mailbox Sent {
 special_use = \Sent
}
mailbox "Sent Messages" {
special_use = \Sent
}
mailbox Trash {
special_use = \Trash
}
prefix = 
separator = /
}
passdb {
 driver = pam
 }
 protocols = imap
 ssl_cert = </etc/ssl/certs/ssl-cert-snakeoil.pem
 ssl_key = </etc/ssl/private/ssl-cert-snakeoil.key
 userdb {
 driver = passwd
```

With that setting, I can observe:
Change the IMAP folder "test_com" -> "test/com" gives an Thunderbird alert box that the character is reserved. That matches expectation, since i defined it as hierarchical separator.
Change the IMAP folder "test_com" -> "test.com" gives a server popup message "[CANNOT] Char not allowed in mailbox name"

What do I have to change to get those '.' in my folder names?

As this seems quite a difficult thing ( I keep looking around I did not yet find anything useful), it would be helpful to know if someone with a standard Ubunutu setup actually can confirm my observation. Maybe I need to take the hard step to just re-install the mail system.

Thanks for the help.

Comment: Did 2 edits with updates to the question due to the comments from DarkPhoenix6 below.

Answer (score -1):

try this

```
sed -i '
/  \# The default however depends on the underlying mail storage format./ {
N
    s_  \# The default however depends on the underlying mail storage format.\n  \#separator =_  \# The default however depends on the underlying mail storage format.\n  \#separator =\n  separator = /_
}' /etc/dovecot/conf.d/10-mail.conf
```

Comment: Thanks for the answer. I can see you are in cryptic mode. No worries, I just found this 400page advanced sed tutorial on the net. I am sure over the next couple of hours I am going to find out what your suggestion is.

Comment: My bad. What this does is set the default separator to a "/"

This should allow you to have a folder with a "." in it.

Comment: Its a actually a single line to be un-commented. I did actually change that before, but must have missed something, because now I do not get a refusal from the server, he just ignores me when I try to change the folder name. I updated the post above with the current output.

Comment: try setting the mail_location to something like

    mail_location = maildir:<yourMailPath>/%d/%n/Maildir

the %d is the domain(s)

and

%u is the email user

assuming  your structure is:

    /var/vmail/example.com/<username>

the line would be

    mail_location = maildir:/var/vmail/%d/%n/Maildir

Comment: @DakrPhoenix6 I tried that setting but it locks me out. I am not sure how to translate it to the Maildir that is installed in the user directories. There is a file in /var/mail/username but nothing with the domain and not really large. However, the first setting got a reaction (took a while?). Thunderbird now gives and Reserver char alert when I try to use '/', but the server gives a  the server gives a popup '[CANNOT] Char not allowed in mailbox name'. Seems to me that "separator = /" is not the resposible setting for not allowing '.' in the imap filenames?

Comment: @CatMan I gather from your output that you get your users from the passwd file however your configuration should not be to different from this MySQL one:

https://workaround.org/ispmail/jessie/setting-up-dovecot

Comment: Thanks for the link. And yes. your are right. In fact I have checked that page before posting. It shows the setting "separator = ." which I tried first. I did not see other stuff connected that issue, though. At least its unclear to me, why user auth affects modifying a folder name with a certain char. User access to the server is OK.Do I overlook something?

Comment: Read the "Hierarchy separators" section in 

http://wiki2.dovecot.org/Namespaces

Comment: I did read that whole section, but as far as I understood it it confirmed that the hierarchy sign is changes as given above. I did not see any clue about a connection to the IMAP folder names.  The only promising hint I got there was the table listing two separators a LayoutSep and NS Sep. The NS sep seems to be what is defined in the config file. Exact function of LayoutSep and where it is defined I did not find. I might not be surprised that the root cause of that '.' in my folder names is not NS, but rather LayoutSep. On the other hand, several other tuts always quote NS